# How to access a base workspace variable from matlab app designer?

Tags: matlab-app-designer

I have a variable ( cell array) created in base workspace in matlab..i am building an app in appdesigner to access the base workspace variable and find the transpose at push of a button.

when i tried to use the variable in callbackfunction i get the error :

undefined function or variable even though the variable defined in base workspace.

Kindly help me with a solution.

Comment: If the only way for you to access some data that the app requires is by reading another workspace, this is usually an indication of bad design. There are various tools to do _what you're asking_ including `global` variables, `appdata`, `evalin`, etc. However, what you probably _should_ do is load the data from a file, or better yet, create it inside the app while it is running. It's hard to suggest a fitting solution without more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I literally just got Matlab 2016 yesterday, and I haven't tried what you're attempting, but I'm guessing it's similar to similar scenarios in functions. So I guess you can try this:

```
localVariableInCallback = evalin('base','nameOfVariableInWorkspace');
```

Where

- *localVariableInCallback* is a local variable in the callback function
- *nameOfVariableInWorkspace* is the variable in your base workspace

Reference: Matlab 'evalin' documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html

I noticed you posted same question twice, and was downvoted. I strongly recommend that you have a look at what they suggested and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your questions.